# Failed to start ipmiutil ipmi_port service

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, ipmi

After upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 16.10, every time when I try to install anything in my laptop I got this error. I tried to manually install impmiutil, but unfortunately even that didn't help me.
Any ideas what else I can do with this ?

```
Setting up ipmiutil (3.0.0-1) ...
Job for ipmi_port.service failed because the control process exited 
 with error code.
See "systemctl status ipmi_port.service" and "journalctl -xe" for 
 details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ipmi_port, action "start" failed.
● ipmi_port.service - ipmiutil ipmi_port service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ipmi_port.service; disabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Հնգ 2017-04-06 04:03:59 +04; 
 10ms ago
Process: 22082 ExecStart=/usr/share/ipmiutil/ipmiutil.setup >/dev/null 
&& /usr/sbin/ipmi_port -b || : (code=exited, status=6)

Ապր 06 04:03:59 aram-X550CC systemd[1]: Starting ipmiutil ipmi_port  
service...
Ապր 06 04:03:59 aram-X550CC systemd[1]: ipmi_port.service: Control 
process exited, code=exited status=6
Ապր 06 04:03:59 aram-X550CC systemd[1]: Failed to start ipmiutil 
ipmi_port service.
 Ապր 06 04:03:59 aram-X550CC systemd[1]: ipmi_port.service: Unit 
 entered failed state.
Ապր 06 04:03:59 aram-X550CC systemd[1]: ipmi_port.service: Failed with 
result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package ipmiutil (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
ipmiutil
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc60Y.png)

Comment: what does `journalctl -xe -u ipmi_port` say...?

Comment: @George, thanks for your time, problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ipmiutil/+bug/1643784

You could manually download the newest version of ipmiutil package and install it manually using `dpkg -i`.
Download available from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/amd64/ipmiutil/3.0.1-1